# Handling time zones in DxScheduler

Tags: calendar, timezone, devexpress

[DxScheduler is the DevExpress Blazor control](https://demos.devexpress.com/blazor/Scheduler) for providing a sophisticated calendar UI. But the questions below are general to the issue of DB to UI presentation of timezones in a calendar.

Are there any problems with the following approach. And a big constraint is the DevExpress does support a timezone for the collection of appointments. It does not support a timezone for each appointment. ([It can be done, but it's work.](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/t1158952/how-can-i-have-different-time-zones-for-each-dxschedulerappointmentitem))

First off, I decided against tracking a time zone per appointment. It can be done, but it's a lot of extra work on my end. Which is not just the time hit, but it means more bugs. (A developer I highly respect said every `if` statement is a bug waiting to happen.) In addition, for 99% of my users, their world in respect to my app will be in their timezone.

Second, this app will be heavily used by people across the U.S. as well as a smattering across the world. People want to see their appointments in their local timezone.

Third, saving everything in "local" time is dangerous. For most uses it'll work but for the cases where it doesn't - I'm screwed. Because there's then no way to understand what timezone a 3:00 meeting is in.

So I'm doing the following.

1. All appointments are stored in the database in UTC.
2. Every user, when they register, sets their timezone.
3. When populating the UI, I read out the appointments and convert them to the user's timezone.
4. The scheduler's timezone is set to the user's timezone.

Any problems with this approach?

Note: Per StackOverflow guidelines, I am not asking for an opinion on what is the best way to do this. I'm asking if there's anything in this approach that's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You indicated:

> ... I decided against tracking a time zone per appointment. ... All appointments are stored in the database in UTC.

This is the main problem with your approach.  While it may appear to avoid bugs, it actually introduces a very real problem that may cause appointments to be off by an hour in the case of a time zone update.

It's important to understand that the various governments of the world make updates to their time zones however they see fit.  This can be a change to either the daylight saving time applicability or start/end dates, or to the standard time zone offset. (Occasionally there can also be a change to the geographic borders of where a time zone applies - but that is much more difficult to track in software than other types of changes.)  When such changes occur, sometime there is adequate notice of the change, and sometimes there is not.  But for argument's sake, let's presume you indeed have  enough notice of a change to keep your systems up to date.

With a UTC-based model, the issue will occur when such a change is made in the period between when an appointment is first recorded, and when it comes into effect.  Here's an example scenario:

- Sometime around September 2022, a user makes an appointment for May 1st, 2023 at 10:00 am.  The user is located in Mexico City.
- Your software looks up the time zone offset and identifies that Mexico City uses UTC-6 but is in UTC-5 for daylight saving time between April and October.  So it uses UTC-5 for this appointment, converting `2023-05-01T10:00-05:00` to `2023-05-01T15:00Z`, storing that UTC time in the database.
- In October 2022, the Mexican government abolished DST in most of Mexico including Mexico City.  You can read about it [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/mexico-abolishes-dst-2022.html).  These changes went into effect in the [2022f release of the IANA TZ Database](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2022-October/000075.html).
- Your system receives the time zone updates, either through its operating system updates, or platform/framework/language/library updates.  This is good, as we don't want to be using outdated data to make time zone conversions.
- May comes around, and that appointment comes due.  Because DST is no longer applicable in Mexico City, UTC-6 is in effect. Your software converts `2023-05-01T15:00Z` retrieved from the database to `2023-05-01T09:00-06:00`.
- The user expected a 10:00 am appointment, but your software gave them a 9:00 am appointment instead.  They show up at 10:00, and have missed their appointment time.

To avoid this problem, keep the following principles in mind:

- **Because one cannot know the future, the "always use UTC" advice is applicable *only* for past or present events.**
- Future events should be stored in terms of the time zone that is applicable for the event.
- In most cases, the applicable time zone identifier (ex: IANA's `"America/Mexico_City"` or Windows' `"Central Standard Time (Mexico)"`) should be stored with the event itself, or with an associated record that belongs to the physical location of the event, as in the case of a business with multiple offices, etc.  However, some scenarios may be based on a variable local time zone, such as with an alarm clock on a user's smartphone.

As for the DevExpress Blazor DxScheduler component, I'm not intimately familiar with that component, but I do see in the docs that it has time zone support, provided through [`DxSchedulerDataStorage.TimeZone`](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxSchedulerDataStorage.TimeZone), [`DxSchedulerAppointmentItem.TimeZoneId`](https://docs.devexpress.com/Blazor/DevExpress.Blazor.DxSchedulerAppointmentItem.TimeZoneId), etc.  It appears to use Windows time zone identifiers rather than IANA's (which seems strange, because Blazor should be using IANA identifiers).  But either way, you should be able to leverage that support to have a time zone with each event.  I would also pay attention to the `.Kind` property on the `DateTime` values the component uses.  In a scheduling component like that one, they should generally be `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` - not `DateTimeKind.Local` or `DateTimeKind.Utc`.

Comment: Thank you - really good point. This makes searching a PITA though because what is all appointments on 10-09-2023 or later when each appointment is a different timezone?

Comment: BTW, my guess is they use `Windows time zone identifiers` because the world of their libraries is Windows and .NET has really good library support for those identifiers.

Comment: Typically, one would have a separate column to track the UTC-based time of the appointment (or the _next_ appointment in the case of a recurring schedule).  Periodically, this data would be updated - especially after a time zone data update.  For efficiency, some systems keep this in a separate table and only track the next N (100, 1000, etc.) appointments coming up.  Others keep 2 to 3 days worth, then recompute nightly.  You might also consider something like [Quartz.net](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) rather than making your own.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I'm considering storing everything with a DateTime & TimeZoneInfo pair - but for searches like give me all appointments over the next week, just search against the DateTime. Because that's how people view their appointments, by their local time. Is this a mistake, or is this reasonable? I will of course convert to UTC for reminders, etc. where I need an exact match. TIA